# How do you obtain a list of all image file names on a wordpress website for replacement?

Tags: images, gallery, list

Good Day, I hope somebody can assist me please. I have to replace/re-upload all the images on a website, as they were uploaded as massive files. I have to downsize all the images, and want to know if there is a way to get a list of file names so that I can downsize the images and replace them, without editing every image one at a time. The source images on the website are 1920x1080, and I need to re-upload as 800 x800 for a lot of them, with a much lower KB/file size. I'm new at this, so would really appreciate some help.Is it possible to extract a list of all the file names?

Comment: Have you considered using a plugin instead? There are several good options available (it's off-topic to recommend specific ones here) that you can install, have them resize all the images on your site automatically, and then either keep the plugin to ensure newly uploaded files get sized properly, or remove the plugin if it's a one-and-done situation.

Comment: Where/how were these images originally uploaded? If they're in the media library WordPress has probably already created downsized versions of an appropriate size. In that case you don't need to reupload them, but you need to update your content to use the downsized versions. How to do that depends on how your website was populated. Are you using a page builder, or just the normal WordPress editor (either of them)?